# JavaScript - how to view raw data for an image

Tags: javascript, file, image-processing

Is it possible to view the raw data for an image file in javascript?

I'm trying to write a script that converts an image into its hex dump.

How can I view the data I'm writing to the image file?

Comment: I'd request it with AJAX and read the resulting data...but I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: You need to precise where you are working  ,client side or server side ? check the file readers and typed arrays server side.

Comment: I found a source code viewer here http://jawjahboy.com/utility/ but I guess it works with ajax.

Comment: The main problem is that I have no idea how to get the source code into a string!!

Comment: Actually, your problem is that you don't know what the term _source code_ means.  Source code is what you write when you create a program.  You're looking to get the _raw image data_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with XHR:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/my/image/file.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // this will accept the response as an ArrayBuffer
xhr.onload = function(buffer) {
    var words = new Uint32Array(buffer),
        hex = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      hex += words.get(i).toString(16);  // this will convert it to a 4byte hex string
    }
    console.log(hex);
};
xhr.send();
```

Look at the doc for [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer)s and [TypedArray](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/)s

And you can see how I use it in testing [here](https://github.com/samlecuyer/fontificate/blob/master/test/fontificate_test.js)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the source code of a file in javascript?

Find the URL for the script and load that into your browser. (Or use Firebug)

Comment: So copy it out of the browser window (or firebug view). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste

Comment: I want to write code and not a cut and paste program where I need another program to actually run my code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.