# Can you acquire raw image data without drawing to a canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you acquire raw image data without drawing to a canvas in javascript?  Can you give an example of this in practice? Thanks!

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12755042/1319187) be your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could acquire that data using an ajax call to that address. Something like

```
$.ajax($self.attr("src"), {
    complete: function (jqxhr) {
        $self.text(jqxhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/x5j7E/) I've prepared that demonstrates that method.