# JavaScript Zlib Decompress

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, arrays, zlib

I'm trying to decompress zlib'ed XML such as the following:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B52P0MZLTdw8ZzQwQzVpZGZVZWc

Uploading to online decompress services works, such as: http://i-tools.org/gzip

In PHP, I'm using this code and works just fine, I get the XML string:

```
$raw = file_get_contents("file_here");
$uncompressed = zlib_decode($raw);
```

However, I want to do this in JavaScript.

- The app is a client-side Chrome extension which uses [chrome.devtools.network](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#event-onRequestFinished) that reads from the network logs
- Reads binary responses. Example at Google Drive link at the top
- JS needs to decompress that response to its original XML and parsed afterwards into object

The only problem I have is the zlib decompress part.

**As of Latest Update, the Decompression Libraries work but unpacking doesn't. Please skip to the Update Sept 16 at the bottom.**

---

I have already tried several JavaScript libraries and still cannot make it work:

**Pako**: https://github.com/nodeca/pako

`unpack()` code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings

```
function unpack(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}

$.get("file_here", function(response){
    var charData    = unpack(response);
    var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);
    var data        = pako.inflate(binData);
    var strData     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
    console.log(strData);
});
```

Error: `Uncaught incorrect header check`

It's the same even placing the response elsewhere:

- `new Uint8Array(response);`
- `pako.inflate(response);`

---

**Imaya's zlib**: https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js

```
$.get("file_here", function(response){
    var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(response);
    var output = inflate.decompress();
    console.log(output);
});
```

Error: `Uncaught Error: unsupported compression method` `inflate.js:60`

Still using Imaya's zlib, combining with this Stack Overflow question:
[Decompress gzip and zlib string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

```
$.get("file_here", function(response){
    var response = response.split('').map(function(e) {
        return e.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(response);
    var output = inflate.decompress();
    console.log(output);
});
```

Error: `Uncaught Error: invalid fcheck flag:29` `inflate.js:65`

---

**dankogai's js-deflate**: https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate

```
console.log(RawDeflate.inflate(response));
```

Output:  empty

---

**augustl's js-inflate**: https://github.com/augustl/js-inflate

```
console.log(JSInflate.inflate(response));
```

Output:  empty

---

**zlib-browserify**: https://github.com/brianloveswords/zlib-browserify

Error: `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

This is just a wrapper for Imaya's zlib. I think this is `requireJS`? I'm not even sure how to use it. Can it even be used without installing anything and just jQuery/JS? The app as mentioned is downloadable Chrome extension with just HTML importing JS files.

---

### UPDATE Sept 16, 2014

It seems the problem is with the **JavaScript** `unpack( )` function. When I use the ByteArray generated by PHP: http://pastebin.com/uDWvK94B, the JavaScript decompression functions work.

PHP unpacking that works:

```
$unpacked = unpack("C*", $raw);
```

For the JavaScript `unpack( )` code that I use, which doesn't work, see top of the post under **Pako** section.

So the new question is, why does JavaScript generate a different ByteArray values than the one generated by PHP.

- Is it really a problem with the `unpack( )` function?
- or is it something when the JS fetches the file, the encoding or whatsoever changes thus bytes get messed up?
- and lastly, what is your suggested fix?

### UPDATE Sept 20, 2014

With more research and some of the answers here giving leads

- **Sebastian S** opening the idea that the problem was in the manner of retrieving data and it had something to do with text encodings
- **user3995789** providing an example that it will work even without the `unpack( )` function, though outside the context of Chrome extensions
- **Isaac** providing examples in the context of Chrome extensions, but still does not work

With that I researched further combining all leads which lead me to a theory that the reason behind all this is that Chrome is unable to get "raw" data through its `request.getContent` function. [See here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#type-Request) for the Chrome documentation for the said function.

As of now, I have taken the issue to Chrome, [see here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415001).

### UPDATE March 24, 2015

Although the problem was not fully resolved, the answer which I think was the most useful to me was from @Sebastian S, who proposed that "the way" I was taking or receiving the data was at fault and a bad conversion was the cause, which is as near as the problem was.

Comment: Are you using the extension with the chrome devtools ?

Comment: yes, I am on devtools that use `chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished` which will later on do a `request.getContent(function(response){` where that `response` is the one I need to decompress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the question you should really be asking is: *How* do you retrieve the compressed data? As soon as it becomes an UTF-16 string, the trouble begins. I'm not even sure, if the conversion from raw byte data to javascript strings is lossless.

As you wrote something about php, I assume you're communicating to some sort of backend. If this is true, there are options to handle binary data with native means. Maybe this can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: Another problem is that I do not have control over the request. The chrome extension I am working on receives data via [chrome.devtools.network](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#event-onRequestFinished), which reads from the network logs and gets the response body from there. the PHP I've been mentioning was just to test decompression, but isn't part of the app.

Comment: If you log out the first few decoded bytes (should be `[120, 156, 237, 157, 91, ...]`) maybe you can see some obvious error like wrong endianness or somthing?

Comment: my latest research leads up related to that. the correct values are `[120,156,237,90,91,83...]` and a latest JavaScript unpack via `charCodeAt()` generates this: `[120, 65533, 65533, 90, 91, 83...]` some are 65533 which I'm currently researching why

Comment: as the chars have variable length, it probably is UTF-8 encoded. Your unpack needs to be adjusted, as the MSB of each byte have special meanings in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery reads in `utf8` format, you have to read the raw file, this function will work.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open('GET', file, true);  
    rawFile.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    rawFile.onload = function (response)
    {
      var words = new Uint8Array(rawFile.response);
       console.log(words[1]);
      console.log(pako.ungzip(words));

    };
    rawFile.send();
}
```

For more information see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12755042/3995789).

Comment: this works as it is, but cannot be used in the Chrome Extensions environment since we read response bodies from the network logs. Is there anyway to store that correct ByteArray values onto a JavaScript variable without doing an XHR?

Comment: what do you mean, `$.get` also does an XHR, how do you read the files within Chrome Extensions, what environment is that? Anyway, I found your problem, accept and give the bounty please. @dragonjet

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting a huge array as a returned value: https://i.gyazo.com/c24144925d957f36209e1334128fd315.png  My file is compressed with the `gzcompress` function from php, any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I followed Isaac's answer it worked! :) Looks like I needed to get it base64 encoded in memory first?

Comment: @NiCkNewman I've got an array too, how did you manage to get the string?

Comment: you don't need `Uint8Array`, use `pako.ungzip(rawFile.response, {to:'string'})`

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you wanna use the zlib decompression inside a chrome extension while reading reponses bodies from the network log.

You need first to retrieve the base64 who will be decompressed. You can achieve this while using the `getContent` method.

```
function zlibDecompress(base64Content){
    // var base64Content        = base64Content.split(',')[1]; // Not sure if need to keep it

    // Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
    var strData     = atob(base64Content);

    // Convert binary string to character-number array
    var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

    // Turn number array into byte-array
    var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

    // Pako inflate
    var data        = pako.inflate(binData, { to: 'string' });

    return data;

}

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
    function(request) {
        request.getContent(
            function(content, encoding){
                if(encoding == 'base64'){
                    var output = zlibDecompress(content);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network#type-Request

Using XMLHttpRequest :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pako.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function zlibDecompress(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function(oEvent) {
        // Base64 encode
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); 
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            base64data      = reader.result;  
            var base64      = base64data.split(',')[1];

            // Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)
            var strData     = atob(base64);

            // Convert binary string to character-number array
            var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

            // Turn number array into byte-array
            var binData     = new Uint8Array(charData);

            // Pako inflate
            var data        = pako.inflate(binData, { to: 'string' });

            console.log(data);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}
zlibDecompress('fileurl');
</script>
```

If you wanna use XMLHttpRequest with chrome extension

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.domain.com/", // The domain that hold the file
    "http://*/" // Or every domain
  ],
  ...
}
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Feel free to ask if you have any questions ;)

Comment: thanks, i see you've been editing your answer. the response I get from the network logs are binary data, as seen on google drive link and not base64 though. The closest I am now to getting correct Uint8Array is [TextEncoding](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) but still interprets unicode characters as 3 bytes

Comment: What do you use to capture the binary through your chrome extension ?

Comment: @dragonjet Did you tried my code while remplacing the    ` var strData     = atob(base64Content);` by ` var strData     = base64Content;` ?

Comment: I use a listener to `onRequestFinished` which returns a request object, which can be used to `request.getContent(function(response){})`. From there, the `response` is the binary data.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, this helped me!

Comment: Awww, I'm getting `uncaught exception: incorrect header check` on Firefox, but w/ Chrome it works. Any idea?